# void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH]) in C

Tags: c, enums

I am making a connect 4 game.

I have searched and I cant seem to find anywhere that will show me what this like is expecting to take.

```
void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH])
```

this is the comment with it;

```
/**
 * In this requirement you are required to display the game board. 
 * The game board should be displayed as shown on the first page of the 
 * assignment specification. 
 * @param board the board to display
 **/
```

I can make the board but I'm unsure how to use that line.

Comment: `void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH]){ /* Code to print the board */ }` -- Look up on functions. That's a function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what more specifically you have for problems with the function?

Comment: I was just hoping someone could explain to me how this works. When I give it a number it comes with this warning. 

warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
      to parameter of type 'enum cell_contents (*)[7]' [-Wint-conversion]
                        display_board(7);

What im hoping for is that it will do my printf loop that prints the board. Does the void make it not return anything?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, we have the function declaration

```
void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH]);
```

Its quite clearly a declaration of a function, that much you must understand as well.

Now if we split it into smaller parts we have this:

- Return type: `void`
- Function name: `display_board`
- Argument: `enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH]`

The return type `void` means that the function will not return anything.

The function name is what you use when calling the function.

The function argument is what the function expects you to pass to the function.

If we further break down the argument declaration (using e.g. [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)) we will learn that the argument variable is named `board`, that it's an array of `BOARDWIDTH` arrays of the `cell_contents` enumeration.

So to call it you first need an array of arrays of the enumeration, and then you just pass it to the function like any other argument to any other function.

Comment: Thank you sir, You are great!